# excel vba macro delete column based on cell content

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a macro to delete columns from a spreadsheet if they have certain content.  All the data is in the first row, of variable length.  I think the problem may have to do with my range selection.  I keep getting subscript out of range when I try to do the search.  Any advice would be appreciated.  :)

```
Sub Disk_Firmware()
   Dim c As Range
   Dim SrchRng As Range
   Dim SrchStr As String
   Set SrchRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").EntireRow
   SrchStr = InputBox("Please enter a search string")
   Do
      Set c = SrchRng.Find(SrchStr, LookIn:=xlvalues)
      If Not c Is Nothing Then c.EntireColumn.Delete
   Loop While Not c Is Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line gives you the error? Your Code works for me too. However one word of caution! Put a check to trap if the user presses `OK` in the InputBox without entering anything. Else your code will enter into an endless loop causing Excel to crash!

Answer (score 1):

Your code works absolutely fine in my VBE. I just added the following:

```
SrchStr = Trim(SrchStr)
```

For that error, the MSDN website suggests that you use a For Next instead of a Do While, so as not to specify index elements.

Comment: Hmm, it is failing on `Set c = SrchRng...`.  I should mention that I am running Excel 2007 SP2.

Comment: Ah, I fixed it.  I got rid of the SrchRng and switched to a For loop.  This works:

    `Sub Disk_Firmware()
       Dim c As Range
       Dim SrchRng As Range
       Dim SrchStr As String
       Set SrchRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").EntireRow
       SrchStr = Trim(InputBox("Please enter a search string"))
       For Each c in SrchRng.Cells
         If c.Value = SrchStr Then c.EntireColumn.Delete
       Next c
    End Sub`

Thanks for the suggestions!  :)  Sorry, it won't let me "Answer" and I'm not sure how to get code to format in a "comment."

Comment: Also, to show your code, press the space bar 4 times so it will show as code. Also, its quite helpful to briefly skim through the about page.